# Getting the hexdump of a given function

Tags: linux, hexdump

I want to get the hexdump of a given function. Until now `objdump -d a.out --start-address=0x400630 and --stop-address=0x400679` is the best solution what I have found, however I do not know how to extract only the opcodes from the output.
For example from this:

```
  4003f0:   48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
  4003f4:   e8 73 00 00 00          callq  40046c
  ...
```

I need only this:

```
  48 83 ec 08 
  e8 73 00 00 00
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use gdb on your program and `x/i` will print out a range of machine instructions.

Comment: Is it possible to do this automatically from a shell script without writing commands manually in `gdb`?

Comment: Yes.  Create a file with your gdb commands and run `gdb -x file`.

Answer (score 0):

May also try to pipe in cut:

```
objdump -d a.out --start-address=0x400630 and --stop-address=0x400679 | cut -b 14-30
```

you probably need to adapt your cut range for your output.